# Pasar de http a https con certificado SSL activado en 1&1

Tags: webservice, web, http, ssl, https

tengo un problema con mi página web hospedada en **1&1**. Tengo activado el certificado SSL de 1&1 y no puedo conectarme desde mi ordenador usando *Dreamweaver* al servidor remoto de 1&1 y por lo tanto no puedo pasar los archivos de **http** a **https** para ver los cambios hechos.

1&1 tiene instalado mi certificado y mi único problema es el antes descrito. ¿Cómo podría conectarme yo desde mi ordenador usando **Dreamweaver** al servidor remoto de 1&1? 
Cuando lo intento en la administración del sitio cambiando **http://ejemplo.com/** a **https://ejemplo.com/** y hago la prueba de conexión, no funciona y me sale este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Está configurado como **SFTP** siguiendo las indicaciones del proveedor.

A ver si alguien puede echarme un cable.

Gracias y saludos de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo varios host en 1&1, te paso las configuraciones correctas:

**FTP seguro para Linux:**
Si tiene un pack de Linux, ingrese la siguiente información en su programa FTP:

*CONFIGURACIÓN*

- Nombre de usuario: Su nombre de usuario FTP (en Linux, el nombre de
  usuario FTP normalmente comienza por "u" o "p", p.ej.: p12345678 o
  u12345678)
- Contraseña: La contraseña del usuario FTP
- Servidor/Host: El nombre o host del servidor FTP (ejemplo.com o homexxxxx.1and1-data.host o accessxxxxx.webspace-data.io, o la IPv4)
- Protocolo: SFTP
- Puerto:22

**FTP seguro para Windows**
Si tiene un pack de Windows, ingrese la siguiente información en su programa FTP:

*CONFIGURACIÓN*

- Nombre de usuario: Su nombre de usuario FTP (en Windows, el nombre de
  usuario FTP normalmente comienza con "ftp", p.ej.: ftp12345678)
- Contraseña: La contraseña del usuario FTP
- Servidor/Host    El nombre de    host del servidor FTP (eejemplo.com o
  homexxxxx.1and1-data.host o    accessxxxxx.webspace-data.io, o la
  IPv4)
- Protocolo: FTPS
- Puerto: 990.

Suerte!